# Legend title from geom_vline

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I am using ggplot2 (v. 2.2.1) in R (v. 3.4.1) to create a histogram that includes vertical lines. I am using the following code to generate the histogram, place the vertical lines, and add the lines to the plot legend:

```
ggplot(data = meanExps, aes(x)) + 
geom_histogram(col = "black",
               fill="lightblue") + 
geom_vline(data = meanData, 
           mapping = aes(xintercept=Vals,
                         linetype=Title, 
                         color = Title),
           size = 1, 
           show.legend = T) +
labs(x = "Exponential Means")
```

Everything is displaying correctly in the plot with the exception of the title of the legend, which is displayed as "Title".

[image: Plot Image]

I would like to change the title of the legend to something else - say, "V. Lines"

I have tried the following code, which gives me the legend (and title) that I want, but also gives me an extra legend that I don't want.

```
ggplot(data = meanExps, aes(x)) + 
geom_histogram(col = "black",
               fill="lightblue") + 
geom_vline(data = meanData, 
           mapping = aes(xintercept=Vals,
                         linetype=Title, 
                         color = Title),
           size = 1, 
           show.legend = T) +
labs(x = "Exponential Means", color = "V. Lines")
```

Here is an image of this plot: 
[image: Plot w/ two legends].

So, my question is this: How do I create a single legend from geom_vline with a title of my choosing?

Comment: All you need is to remove the linetype legend: `yourPlot + guides(linetype = FALSE)`

Comment: Add a title to the linetype, then it will be merged with the colour ledgend `labs(x = "Exponential Means", color = "V. Lines", linetype = "V.lines") `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the title for both aesthetics at the same time if you want them to be merged.

```
labs(x = "Exponential Means", color = "V. Lines", linetype = "V. Lines")
```

Comment: Thanks Andres. A point of clarification for anyone who reads this: the text following 'color =' and 'linetype =' must be identical or you will get two legends.